# Reverse Geocoding Current User Location, How To?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a working map in XCode that zooms in on the user's location (obviously, for the program, it'll default to Apple's Headquarters, etc.)

Here is my implementation file for "MyLocationViewController:"

```
#import "MyLocationViewController.h"

@interface MyLocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyLocationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.001;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is my header file for the previous file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MyLocationViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

Now, my question is this:

I want to reverse geocode the user's current location, giving such information as street (number and appt., if applicable), city, and state. Preferably, I would want to have it automatically show up after the zooming-in process is complete, showing itself on top of the blue dot. However, after consulting the Apple guide to reverse geocoding, I was still left confused as to how to do it, and searching around didn't prove too fruitful.

Please note: I want this reverse geocoding procedure to show up as an address on top of the user's location. The user SHOULD NOT have to type something and click a button somewhere off screen to see what the address is--it should be automatic.

Oh, and by the way, I am no expert in Objective-C. I just started a few weeks ago doing this kind of  stuff, so please don't throw around complicated terminology all over my question. It gets me nowhere.

Comment: There is a reverse fri coding class that does this  look it up in the docs.

Comment: What do you mean "reverse fri coding class?"

Searching doesn't show a thing.

Comment: `MapKit` has a reverse geocoder class.  Docs:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/mkreversegeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html .I suggest you have a go and come back with a specific problem if you have any difficulties.

Comment: @TZK203 I meant "geo coding" but auto complete on my phone messed it up. Anyway, this has been asked many times on SO before. Just search for iOS reverse geo coding.

Comment: That doesn't help me, Fog. 

You realize that this site has had these questions before, but they relate mostly to button inputs and UILabels, not actual MKMapView interactions that didn't involve an intermediate. They're not direct and generally do not lead me anywhere where there is progress.

I suggest that in the future, you at least attempt to give me a starter method or something so I can research the rest. Instead, you just wasted your time telling me to research it--a simple answer would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote this simple function that will get the user's location from the mapView and attempt to reverse geocode it. Code and comments are pretty straight-forward. Let me know if you have questions.

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeUserLocation {
    // create your geocoder object
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    // get the user's location from the map view
    CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;

    // tell the geocoder to reverse geocode the user's location
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:userLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        // if there was an error
        if (error) {
            // handle error here...
            return;
        }

        // get the first "placemark" object from the result array
        CLPlacemark *firstPlacemark = [placemarks firstObject];

        // get the address dictionary from the placemark object
        NSDictionary *addressDictionary = firstPlacemark.addressDictionary;

        // break the dictionary into components for display if you'd like
        NSString *street = addressDictionary[@"Street"];
        NSString *city = addressDictionary[@"City"];
        NSString *state = addressDictionary[@"State"];
        NSString *zip = addressDictionary[@"Zip"];
     }];
}
```

I simulated a location to test this out, the coordinates were 42.9897, -71.45435, (somewhat nearby where I am) and the result dictionary I got from the first placemark object was:

```
{
    City = Manchester;
    Country = "United States";
    CountryCode = US;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "274 Merrimack St",
        "Manchester, NH  03103-4721",
        "United States"
    );
    PostCodeExtension = 4721;
    State = NH;
    Street = "274 Merrimack St";
    SubAdministrativeArea = Hillsborough;
    SubLocality = "East End";
    SubThoroughfare = 274;
    Thoroughfare = "Merrimack St";
    ZIP = 03103;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike! This worked well for my project.